# Proper submenu using only HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm trying to write a simple HTML+CSS menu without any absolute positioning or JS. My problem is regarding submenus, where it either expand the current selected item or displace it:

[image: submenu problem]

The HTML is straightforward:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Folder 1
    <ul>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

And so is the CSS:

```
#menu, #menu ul {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 180px;
}

#menu li ul {
    background-color: cyan;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    right: -168px;
    width: auto;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

#menu li {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#menu li:hover {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I thought the submenu could only affect the layout after being repositioned, which seems
to not be the case here. I'm a bit at a loss.

Comment: You need absolute positioning to prevent elements from being "displaced". That is what absolute positioning is for.

Comment: @Diodeus: `position: absolute` means "don't touch your parent's layout and the put the element at x", and `position: relative` means "change your parent's layout and reposition the element"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this type of menu pattern, you should use `position:relative` on the parent `LI` of the sub-menu, and `position:absolute` on the `UL` child menu. The allows the child element to appear outside of the layout flow, relative to its parent.

It's also good practice to put all non-position styling on the `A`-tag inside each `LI` and use `display:block`. It would be difficult for you to style the text on "Folder 1" without it.

Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/jejNy/127/

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it. `position: absolute` does prevent any changes to the parent `li`, but the sumbenu `ul` needs to be moved relative to where it should originally be, which can't be done with `position: absolute`, nor by moving its containing `li`.

Comment: position:relative sets the origin point for absolutely-positioned children.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute` on the ul and `position:relative` on the LI:

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Folder 1
      <ul>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu, #menu ul {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 180px;
}

#menu li ul {
    background-color: cyan;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:-1px;
    left: 178px;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

#menu li {
    position:relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#menu li:hover {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Check out this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tpKdx)