# Set focus on hidden element on hover jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, focus

I have a hidden list which is hidden using `display:none` in CSS.

When I hover on a `<span>` list item, I would like to show this hidden list. This is a piece of cake to achieve in jQuery:

```
$('#id').hover(function () {
   $('#hidden').toggle();
});
```

My problem is that the hidden list is displayed right underneath a footer bar which is at the bottom of my page, so when it is set to `block`/visible and is shown, the user has to scroll down to see it, at which point the element becomes hidden since the hover event is no longer triggered.

I have tried automatically scrolling to the bottom of the element and ensuring that the hidden element is also included in the `hover` event selector which I thought might do it:

```
$('#service-footer-list').scrollTop($('#service-footer-list').scrollHeight);
```

But this didn't help.

What I need to do is bring this hidden element into view without the user needing to scroll the page. How can this be achieved?

Here is a sample of the markup I'm working with:

```
<div class="footer">
   <div class="footer-container">
        <ul id="footer-list">
            <li id="ftr-service-list">
                <span>Service list</span>
            </li>
            <li id="ftr-contact"><a href="foo">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="service-footer-list">
        <ul class="service-list-dropdown">
            <li><span>Service title</span></li>
            <li><span>Service title</span></li>
            <li><span>Service title</span></li>
            <li><span>Service title</span></li>
            <li><span>Service title</span></li>
            <li><span>Service title</span></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

The `service-footer-list` needs to be shown when hovering the `Service list` `<span>` element.

Comment: You need to use CSS + absolute positioning.

Comment: @Diodeus Can you elaborate further?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154212/proper-submenu-using-only-htmlcss

Comment: @Diodeus This doesn't really help when the list is flush to the bottom of the page. The list is shown on hover and you still need to scroll down to see it. It would work if I positioned the element in view but it's being rendered off screen

Comment: @DGibbs are you allowed to change the position of the #service-footer-list? Or does #service-footer-list HAVE to start off flushed to the bottom of the page? If you can change the position, what you can try is make the position of #service-footer-list absolute and pick where you want it to be on the screen.

Comment: @user2719875 Unfortunately, that is the position in the design and I'm unable to change it

Comment: I ended up getting the jquery scroll method working, thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by scrolling to the menu list after it is made visible:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var services = $('#service-footer-list');
    if (!IsTouchDevice()) 
    {
        $('.footer #ftr-service-list span, #service-footer-list, #ftr-service-list').mouseenter(function () {
            if (!services.is(":visible")) {
                $(services).show();
                $('#ftr-service-list').addClass('toggle-service-arrow');
                $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: $(services).offset().top }, 800);
            }
        });
        $('#site-main').mouseenter(function () {
            if (services.is(":visible")) {
                $('#ftr-service-list').removeClass('toggle-service-arrow');
                $(services).slideUp(500);
            }
        }); 
    } 
});
```